# "output-wide" audio equalizer in xenial

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio

I have an old pair of speakers that has an annoyingly loud bass response.  Switching back and forth between these speakers and any other speakers makes the effect even more noticeable.

I admit I could just buy a better pair of speakers, but I feel like this problem should be able to be solved with software, now that we live in the future of pulseaudio.

How can I set up a pulseaudio equalizer filter that only (and always) affects one output?

Alternately, is there a system-wide equalizer that actually works in 16.04?  All the instructions I can find come from 2013, and none of the software indicated therein seems to be pre-built for anything past 15.04, which doesn't inspire confidence.